# creating a copy of a table without indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

1. I selected from a view `myview` that was based on another view and a table `mytable` with no indexes, the query ran for **40 minutes**
2. I added 5 indexes to `mytable` and reran `myview` and the query ran for **3 minutes**
3. I made a copy of mytable like this:

   **select * into mytableNEW
   from mytable**
4. Please notice that no indexes were copied.
5. I reran `myview` (not forgetting to point to the new table), and it took **3 minutes!!**

**question:** Why did my query initially take 40 minutes without indexes, but after creating indexes on the table and then copying the data (**without indexes**) to another table, the query sped up very significantly??

Comment: A view is a query, not data, not a table.  Unless you materialise it, which you can do by adding indexes.  Selecting from a view is otherwise just like copying the views code into your main query.

Comment: @dems the view is based on the table mytable in question (the one i added indexes to)

Comment: possibly also because SQL had the data cached

Comment: @greg in this case, how can i scramble the data in the new table?

Comment: clear the cache (note this will clear the cache for the whole server, so be careful using it on a live server): http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1360/clearing-cache-for-sql-server-performance-testing/

Comment: @greg thanks! what is the risk of clearing the cache for the whole server?

Comment: @Greg i cleared the cache, and it was still very very fast. i cleared the cache only on the specific database, should i clear the cache on the entire server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (which is too long for a comment) is a suboptimal query plan for the view.

The query plan for a view is based on when the view is first run, not on the current run.  Over time, the table changed, the environment changed, but the view continued to use the original query plan.  I suspect that it was doing nested loop joins, and the execution engine is smart enough to dynamically find and use the indexes, even without recompiling the query.

When you repointed the view to the new table, the view was recompiled for the current environment, so the execution plan was optimal.

This is a guess.  A difference of 40 minutes due to cache misses seems very large, unless the data is really, really big.

Comment: but there werent any indexes in the new table

Comment: Right.  But the optimizer chose a hash or merge join instead of a nested loop join.  That is probably a much faster option.

Comment: why cant all joins be hash joins?

Comment: I have seen queries go from > 10-15mins on the first run to ~ 1 min on subsequent runs. It was a lot of data and it was a fairly complex where clause on non-indexed columns